# Simplest way to store data and pull it into Enterprise Wiki Page

Tags: list, web-part, wiki, data, enterprise-wiki

I am attempting to build an Enterprise Wiki in Sharepoint to document some of the typical processes we do in our IT helpdesk. I really like the organization of a wiki for its ability to interconnect pages. The first type of page I am trying to create is one for each of our customers. I have created a Sharepoint list of all our customers with fields like address, contact info, email host, etc., and would like to insert the row corresponding to each customer into their respective wiki page.

I have tried inserting the list Web Part into the page but I cannot see an obvious way to filter the list to show only the row for a particular customer. Is this possible with Sharepoint lists or should I be storing the customer data some other way?

Thanks.